# How to express a variable as a function of 2 others in a dataframe composed of 3 vectors

Tags: r, dataframe

I know it is fundamental but I can't find the trick ...

Here is an exemple :

`Species <- c("dark frog",rep(c("elephant","tiger","boa"),3),"black mamba")
Year <- c(rep(2011,4),rep(2012,3),rep(2013,4))
Abundance <- c(2,4,5,6,9,2,1,5,6,8,4)
df <- data.frame(Species, Year, Abundance)`

I would like to obtain another dataframe (3 rows *5 columns) with the abundance values in function of the species as the column names (each species appearing thus only one time) and the years as the row names (appearing one time also).

May someone help me please ?

Comment: Essentially `reshape(df, idvar="Year", timevar="Species", direction="wide")` as well.

Comment: Thank you ! Yes it works as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
> xtabs(Abundance~Year+Species, data=df)
      Species
Year   black mamba boa dark frog elephant tiger
  2011           0   6         2        4     5
  2012           0   1         0        9     2
  2013           4   8         0        5     6
```

The class for the above is a `table`, so if you prefer a `data.frame` instead, you can try:

```
library(tidyr)
new.df<- spread(df, key = Species, value = Abundance)
  Year black mamba boa dark frog elephant tiger
1 2011          NA   6         2        4     5
2 2012          NA   1        NA        9     2
3 2013           4   8        NA        5     6
```

If you want 0s instead of `NA` add the following line:

```
new.df[is.na(new.df)]<- 0
```

Comment: Exactely, thanks ! As a matrix, it's perfect but as I turn it into a data frame it doesn't keep the same structure... I got 177 species in fact !

Comment: @J.marine I just realized that myself, so I edited the answer to include a second solution.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! It really deblocks me !